# Serviço com lista de carros e modelos

Tags: javascript, html, plugin

Boa tarde,

Estou para desenvolver um site na qual será necessário preencher qual o modelo do carro, marca e ano. Gostaria de saber se vocês conhecem algum serviço web que me traga essas informações ou eu terei que inseri-las manualmente?

Abraços!

Comment: Penso que isso possa ajudar http://fipeapi.appspot.com/

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: [inserir a descrição do link aqui](http://fipeapi.appspot.com/)

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Jonatas,

Tu terá que construir um serviço que busque essas informações em webservice, no Brasil não sei qual serviço tens pois não trabalhei com isso mas um exemplo de api é este caso venha a calhar:

https://developer.cars.com/apis

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Existe um scraper da tabela FIPE que pode ser usado como base para o que você deseja:

https://github.com/Sorackb/FipeReader

E no mesmo repositório há um serviço do site antigo da FIPE que pode ser modificado com base no primeiro link para atender ao que você precisa:

https://github.com/Sorackb/RESTFulFipe

Comment: Muito obrigado!